# Object/Item out of UICollectionView cells instead of index?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode4.5, uicollectionview

I've been trying to save the state or order of cells in a UICollectionView after they have changed locations in the UICollectionView. When I use indexPathsForVisibleItems I get indexes that are always in the same order. They do not reflect order change. If I could get the object at each indexPath I could at least make an attempt to iterate through them to get the resulting order.

I used this code. And found that it returned a refreshed state of indexPaths in [0,0]. The ordering is always the same because the it tells me what cells have something in them not what is in each cell. I just don't know enough or where to start to get the object/item in each cell.

```
NSArray *visible = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
NSMutableArray *rowsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[visible count]];
[visible enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSIndexPath *indexPath, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [rowsArray addObject:@(indexPath.item)];
```

I need the items or objects at each location. How do I iterate through all the cell locations to retrieve the item there. I plan on using the count of an array used to populate the UICollectionView to loop through all the locations and get the object stored there. There is only one section and cells seem to be storing objects like this `<Slide: 0x7585200>`

The function above returns NSLogs in this format `"<NSIndexPath 0x8490390> 2 indexes [0, 0]"`

I need to get what is in that location.

I'm not familiar with NSIndexPath or it's formatting. Even just the command/function would help for me to get an object out. Thanks.

(Addendum) I'm think of using something like `[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];` Not sure what I can store it in.

Comment: Look at the NSIndexPath UIKit Additions reference.

Comment: It looks like I can use cellForItemAtIndexPath. What can I store that in? I'm new to Objective-C and the "types" are giving me a problem. I was gonna do something like `[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];`

I don't know what I can put that in.

Comment: If you're new to Objective-C, then perhaps collection views are not the best place to start. cellForRowAtIndexPath is a data source method that's called by the collection view, not by you. If you want to learn about collection views, you should watch the WWDC 2012 video, "Introducing Collection Views".

Comment: Thanks. I'm just looking to get something identifiable out of each cell so I can match it up with an array and figure out what the new order is after something has been moved. The hardest part of what I'm doing. I will try and find the video and look at the whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CollectionView is a collection of UIViews (call UICollectionViewCell). Each cell has an indexPath (section,row) mean the layout position in collectionView content. In the case you has 1 section, section always = 0.

visibleCells mean all cells visible on screen at that time (visible in scroll frame or collectionView frame).
indexPathsForVisibleItems = indexPath array of visibleCells

cellForItemAtIndexPath is a method to get a collectionViewCell at any indexPath you want, often use to get cell when select:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell);
}
```

Investigate more from Apple UICollectionView video and example:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/